# How to center geom_spoke around their origin

Tags: r, ggplot2

The examples clearly show that [`geom_spoke`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_spoke.html) draws lines originating at (**`x`**, **`y`**) of length **`radius`** pointing in the direction specified by **`angle`**:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + geom_spoke(aes(angle = angle), radius = 0.5)
```

[image]

What is the simplest reusable way to center the spokes around (**`x`**, **`y`**)?

I prefer not to modify my data for it (that would be less easily reusable) or do inline trigonometry (also less reusable). I don’t mind if “radius” becomes “diameter” in the solution.

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest way to do this is going through the whole process of creating a [`Position`](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/v3.1.0/R/position-.r) subclass like e.g. in [`position_nudge`](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/v3.1.0/R/position-nudge.R)

```
position_center_spoke <- function() PositionCenterSpoke

PositionCenterSpoke <- ggplot2::ggproto('PositionCenterSpoke', ggplot2::Position,
  compute_panel = function(self, data, params, scales) {
    # xend/yend is computed by this point, so shortcut!
    data$x <- 2*data$x - data$xend
    data$y <- 2*data$y - data$yend
    #data$x <- data$x - data$radius*cos(data$angle)
    #data$y <- data$y - data$radius*sin(data$angle)

    # After shifting, the spoke needs to have diameter length,
    # but I’m not sure if the radius is still used anywhere.
    data$radius <- 2*data$radius

    # Now the scales would need to be retrained,
    # But compute_panel doesn’t allow that and
    # compute_layer “should not be overridden”
    data
  }
)
```

Now you can easily use it:

```
expand.grid(x = 1:10, y=1:10) %>%
  mutate(angle = runif(100, 0, 2*pi), speed = runif(100, 0, sqrt(0.1 * x))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_spoke(aes(angle = angle, radius = speed), position = 'center_spoke')
```

[image: position = 'center_spoke']